# how do you find dungeons in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been searching for ages, but I only very rarely happen to find a dungeon. Does anyone know if there is a way to find dungeons that is 100% acurate?

Comment: Is using external programs a valid option for you? Because otherwise it'll be just "keep digging"

Comment: I have AMIDST, but that can't find dungeons whick I think is pretty bad.

Comment: although if you know of a mod that finds them please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Dungeons in Minecraft are randomly generated throughout the map/ground and the only way to find them without mods or third-party programs is to "keep digging", as Arperum posted.

EDIT - This only works near the surface of desert biomes, but you can find square depressions on the ground, caused by the sand falling into the space of the dungeon. Then you can just dig down.

Comment: but there must be some 100% acurate way to find them without using external programmes apart from AMIDST.

Comment: Do you know of any mods that can find them for you(If possible, compatible with or requires minecraft forge for 1.7.2)? If you do, could you let me know please.

Comment: I suggest using the compass finder mod.

Comment: what does that mod do then?

Comment: It uses a compass to show you where Dungeons/Diamonds are.